# How to add htmltable row inside <tbody> from C# codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following table structure in HTML.

```
<table id="myTable" runat="server">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Column1</th>
           <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody >

   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add htmltable rows inside the tbody part.I have searched stackoverflow. There, it is suggested to use tablesection for tablerows. But HTMLTable rows(I mean HTMLControl) does not have that table section property.

Here is what I tried.But it is not defining table sections.

```
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
row .Cells.Add(cell1);

HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
row.Cells.Add(cell2 );

myTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Please ,suggest me how can I add the tablerow to inside html table tbody tag. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why not create the entire table in code behind? Or use a GridView perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Table table = new Table();
TableRow tblRow;
TableCell tblCell;

tblRow= new TableRow();
tblRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
tblCell= new TableCell();
tblCell.Text = "Header";
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCell);
table.Rows.Add(tableRow);

tblRow= new TableRow();
tblRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
tblCell= new TableCell();
tblCell.Text = "Body";
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCell);
table.Rows.Add(tblRow);

tblRow= new TableRow();
tblRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
tblCell= new TableCell();
tblCell.Text = "Footer";
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCell);
table.Rows.Add(tblRow);

WebForm.Controls.Add(table);
```

Comment: Is it not possible for html controls?

Comment: No, These are System.Web.UI.WebControls. I want to do the same thing on HtmlTable(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls).

Comment: Yes.. I am sorry.. Its an overlook. This code creates THead.